# How to open a View on button click in window.open as a popup in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

Basically I am new in angularJs do not know what approach to be follow in opening a View in a popup window on button click.
I am using hybrid application angular js with MVC.
Not using routing concept in angularJs. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You just need to serve view template with necessary scripts so it is able to bootstrap a separate app in this new window. Totally the same as you already do in your main window app.

Comment: what you can try is make the div a popup in which you are loading your view. and then onclick of a button change the view and trigger the popup open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $modal service of angularJS and pass you view as template;

```
  $modal.open({
    template: Template,       
    size: 'md'
  });
```